# How to grant access to root on mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, permissions

Hi I have followed the instructions mentioned on [Mysql reset root users to default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843735/mysql-reset-root-users-to-default). (answer by Nthalk) But I get a new error. My intent is that root should get all permissions. 
Any ways to get over this issue ?

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by "" with grant option;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without being logged in as `root` to start with:

```
mysql -u root
```

The best way to change the password is:

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'new password'
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to understand where I am going `wrong.root@m:~/git/commons.git/glide> whoami`
root
`root@m:~/git/commons.git/glide> mysqladmin -u root password '****'`
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'