# MySQL Reset Default Root Login

Tags: mysql

I somehow changed my root login for my local MySQL. Specifically, I went through [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) Spring guide, which includes creating a MySQL user, *springuser*. Not sure if I did something wrong, but now when I try logging in to MySQL as root (*root*, *password*), it fails:

[image]

... but logging in as spring user works (*springuser*, *ThePassword*):

[image]

Can I somehow change/reset my root login credentials while I am longer able to login as root?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843735/mysql-reset-root-users-to-default) with no luck (predictably, as I assume springuser does not have root access):

[image]

I also tried [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html), but got this error:

[image]

So I created that dir (...\data) and ran the init command (after shutting down MySQL) and it looked like it worked (no error), but then when I try logging in again I get Access Denied:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the Windows equivalent of this:

Stop `mysqld`
Restart it with `—skip-grant-tables —skip-networking`
Connect to it (not exactly certain if you will need to provide a user)

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password('newpassword') where user='root';
flush privileges;
\q
```

stop `mysqld`
restart `mysqld` without the above flags

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me was to reinstall MySQL.